# Facebook Graph API & ColdFusion: "Param no_story must be a boolean"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion

I'm trying to post an image to an album via the Facebook Graph API with following ColdFusion-Code:

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://graph.facebook.com/#albumid#/photos/">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="access_token" value="#access_token#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="file" name="source" file="#img_dir#\dummy.jpg" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="message" value="foo bar" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="no_story" value="true" />
</cfhttp>
```

If I omit `no_story=true`, the whole thing works perfectly, however I need this attribute to prevent the post from appearing on my wall. I'm getting this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Param no_story must be a boolean","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8 WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Param no_story must be a boolean" Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * X-FB-Rev: 1568945 Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-store Facebook-API-Version: v2.2 Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT X-FB-Debug: Vt7Viz/nlNfsQDDfNKtVuBjfgjDiWPFxYb0TAEpJJa9NjrR+TrEB8nuMOerQJYMX9E2e1CeqfBZT70/1KODErg== Date: Wed, 21 Jan 2015 12:13:31 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 98
```

I have tried following variations:

```
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="no_story" value="TRUE" />
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="no_story" value="True" />
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="no_story" value="#true#" />
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="no_story" value="#JavaCast('boolean', true)#" />
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="no_story" value="1" />
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="no_story" value="Yes" />
```

None of these worked.

Comment: Can you show your post request body, As in what the browser shows what data it is actually posting. Use dev tools in the browser to find it.

Comment: @haxtbh Unfortunately this is happening server-side. I'm trying to find a way to see what data is posted.

Comment: Check the current status here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/855430617846913/

Comment: @Boris - In case the link breaks, can you post a brief summary of what it says?

Comment: Yep, will do. Currently still working on it.

Answer (score -1):

Difficult to test that out, but I suspect maybe it is passing the text as opposed to the boolean value. Maybe try:

```
<cfset mytruebool = True>
```

Then:

```
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="no_story" value="#mytruebool#" />
```

The key difference being no quotes on the cfset assignment.

Comment: Steve Oliphant has posted a plausible solution a few hours ago to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/855430617846913/, interested to hear if that works.